# Why is json_decode not converting this curl header response from a string into an object?

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl, http-headers

I am making a login call to a web service, which if successful responds with a token in the header. Is it possible to convert this response from a string to an object?

For other responses from the web service I can use `json_decode` to convert the response from a string to an object. Then I can access the properties I need, such as X-AUTH-TOKEN here. In this instance, json_decode returns `NULL`.

Hopefully this isn't too large a block of code, I felt like each line here is fairly relevant to this issue or identifying what I'm missing. Currently I am settling to break the string using `explode` etc. I assume there is a more elegant approach, but I can't find an answer here. Thanks in advance.

**My Class File**

```
public function login($username, $password) {
        $url = $this->base_url()."login";
        $headers = array(
            "username: $username",
            "password: $password"
        );
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        $response = $this->checkResponse($ch);
        return $response;
}

public function checkResponse($ch) {
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if (curl_errno($ch) !== 0) {
            return curl_errno($ch);
        } else {
            $arr = array($httpcode, $response);
            return $arr;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
```

**My Login File**

```
$data = $user->login($username, $password);
if (is_array($data)) {
    if ($data[0] !== 200) {
        ......
    } else {
        $response = json_decode($data[1);
        // do stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Is your string actually JSON?

Comment: The author of the web service thinks so.